# Declaring Arrays of Arrays in Bigquery

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I'm creating a bigquery procedure to collect data from an array through a function that contains the Array

This is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_DATASET.MY_FUNCTION() AS (
(
    select [
      ['DATA1','DATA1PARAM1'],
      ['DATA2','DATA2PARAM2']
     ] as arrayTest
  )
);
```

`Cannot construct array with element type ARRAY<STRING> because nested arrays are not supported`

This is the procedure, where I declare the variable and set it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_DATASET.MY_PROCEDURE()
BEGIN

  DECLARE tablesArray ARRAY<STRING>;

  SET tablesArray = MY_DATASET.MY_FUNCTION();

END;
```

`Cannot coerce expression BILLING_COMPARE.arrayTablesCartografiaToCompare() to type ARRAY<STRING>`

**How can I declare an Array of Arrays or what is the best way to do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of an array is not allowed. However, an array of a struct with an array is possible:

```sql
With test AS (
(
    select [
      struct(['DATA1','DATA1PARAM1'] as data),
      struct(['DATA2','DATA2PARAM2'])
     ] as arrayTest
  )
)
SELECT * from test, unnest(arrayTest) with offset
```

Comment: OK, and how do you have to declare that in the procedure to set it in a variable?

Comment: `DECLARE tablesArray array<Struct<col_name array<STRING>>>;`

Comment: In this case col_name is arrayTest? I don't understand what it refers to

Comment: I have managed to fetch the data, but now I need to separate 'DATA1' from 'DATA1PARAM1', I am doing SELECT tablesArray[OFFSET(0)], but this returns 'DATA1' and 'DATA1PARAM1', how can I get the data separately?

Comment: `SELECT arrayTest[safe_offset(0)].data[safe_offset(0)] from test` 0 and 0 for data1, 0 and 1 for data1param2, 1 and 1 for data2param2